# Formal Definition of weak, strong, and hypersingularities?

Tags: integral-equations, singular-integrals

In the field of integral equations, specifically boundary element methods, we often deal with integrals containing weak, strong, and hyper singularities.  For a 2D integral, the singularities look like 1/r (weakly singular), 1/r^2 (strongly singular), and 1/r^3 (hypersingular).  For a 1D integral, its ln(r) (weak), 1/r (strong), 1/r^2 (hyper).

I'm looking for some kind of formal definition of these singularities, and a reference that I can cite for it.  I do understand that the strongly singular and hypersingular kernels only legitimately exist as CPV and HFP integrals, but I don't have any more depth than that.

This is my first post on stack exchange, so sorry if my post is incorrect in some way.